# How to pass computed properties from route to component

Tags: ember.js

Taking the following as an example:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    {{magnus-component name=firstName}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/magnus-component">
  <!-- Doesn't appear -->
    {{name}}
  </script>
```

...and

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  name: "Magnus",
  surname: "Womble",
  fullName: Ember.computed('name', 'surname', function(){
    return this.get('name') + ' '+this.get('surname');
  })
});
```

Which can be found in the following jsbin:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/higako/edit?html,js,output

How do you correctly pass the fullName property to the component template?

Comment: Bit late to the party but since the fullName relates to your model's attributes, might be worth having the computed property on the model instead?

Answer (score 6):

You should move your logic from `IndexRoute` to `IndexController`:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  name: "Magnus",
  surname: "Womble",
  fullName: Ember.computed('name', 'surname', function(){
    return this.get('name') + ' '+this.get('surname');
  })
});
```

And then, if you use:

```
{{magnus-component name=fullName}}
```

instead of (`firstName` isn't defined anywhere):

```
{{magnus-component name=firstName}}
```

It will work.

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nilegogizo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for that, um... the demo doesn't work! But nonetheless I understand your logic. The bigger issue, though, is that Ember are planning to deprecate controllers which leaves me wondering how to future-proof this.

Comment: It does work for me - http://i.imgur.com/kkbCRXP.png. About future, well, you should leave the logic in Route and pass `fullName` in model property. So you could pass `model.fullName` instead of `fullName` to route or component. All data should be acquired in Route and then passed in model property to your controller/component. Then you wouldn't have issues when components replace controllers.

Comment: The link you have up there is different from the one in your comment. That explains why it didn't work.The thing is that my actual use case is a little more complicated. I want to pass the results of a  function that involves a store#getAll call to the component. Obviously, I wouldn't normally do that from a model. I apologise for the less than adequate question in that regard.

Comment: Aren't controllers being deprecated? is there a way to access computed properties from the route?